# How to create Index using AOT?

Tags: indexing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aot

Basically I am a database Admin, New to Dynamics AX, How to create Index (Clustered and Non Clustered Index) in Dynamic AX Using AOT?

If I synchronize the AX, The index will be removed?

Is there any method available to create Index with Include Clause in AX 2009 Edition?

How to create index using Jobs?

Comment: What tables do you want to add indexes to? What fields do you want to include?

Answer (score 3):

Do not mess with AX tables, fields, views or indexes using SQL DDL. Because any updates done outside AX may be deleted when synchronizing.

Links:

- [How to create an index in AX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa607289%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)
- [Index properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa881522%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)
- [Best practices for index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa617587%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)
- [Cluster indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa623224%28v=ax.50%29.aspx)

[Included columns](http://dev.goshoom.net/en/2012/04/included-columns-in-ax2012/) in indexes are available in AX 2012, but not in AX 2009.

While creating indexes from an AX job [is possible](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/36641/275536.aspx), it is not worth it, because you will have to manually consider each index.

**Update:**

Just to be clear, unlike other environments, indexes in AX are not done by writing scripts, they are done by manually adding or changing meta-data properties as described in the first link. The actual SQL database indexes are created when the table is synchronized which usually is done automatically when the meta-data are saved.

Comment: +1 DB Admins always think it is okay to just steam into a DB (particularly AX) without any knowledge of the software itself.

Comment: Could you plz suggest some X++ script to add index using AOT? Iam trying to create some missing index, so only few index need to be created.

Comment: If only few, do them by drag and drop. If you are an expert X++ hacker go ahead: http://techstack.com/forum/microsoft-dynamics-ax/57528-8235-1-how-create-index-table-x.html, beware it is not fully working :)